# The next number in series

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the next number in the following series:

12, 35, 81, 173, 357 , ___

I am not able to find the answer. Please explain.

Comment: The next number is 1.

Comment: Looks like $x_{n+1}=2x_n+11$ will fit.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12%2C+35%2C+81%2C+173%2C+357+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the differences between consecutive terms:

$$\begin{align*}
&35-12=23\\
&81-35=46\\
&173-81=92\\
&357-173=184
\end{align*}$$

Can you find a pattern now?

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, the next number in sequence can be arbitrary unless you have some kind of structure in the series, like Fibonacci's or Lucas's sequence. So for example 1 is as good answer as $e^{e^{39}}-\sqrt{\pi}^\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A hint

$12+2^0\cdot23=35$

$35+2^1\cdot23=81$

$81+2^2\cdot23=173$

$173+2^3\cdot23=357$

Thus $n_k=12+23\cdot \left(2^{k+1}-1\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Well,

12+**23**=35

35+**46**=81

81+**92**=173

173+**184**=357

so the adding things (in bold) in between multiplies by $2$ each time starting from $+23$, so to get the next number, just multiply the last adding number, which is $184$, by $2$, to add $368$ to $357$, so you'll get $725$.